# WSO2 for real time semantic applications

Tags: wso2

I would like to know, if it is possible to build an application using WSO2. The problem is I need to receive sensor data’s from different devices. Process those data’s in real time and store meaningful information’s semantically using OWL. I am little confused with the type of WOS2 products that I need to consider for developing thise kind of application. In future I need to scale up this system with increase in devices.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at WSO2 Complex Event Processor (CEP) for real-time event processing requirements. Please go through the documentation to get an idea.
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/CEP210

Thanks,
Dileepa